# Error installing Ruby 1.8.6 and openssl using RVM under Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, openssl, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 1.8.6 on Snow Leopard using rvm.

I tried:
rvm install ruby-1.8.6-p111

and got an error explaining make couldn't find openssl.
make[1]: *** [openssl_missing.o] Error 1

I then tried:
rvm install ruby-1.8.6-p111 -C --with-openssl-dir=/System/Library/OpenSSL
(Snow Leopard seems to come with openssl and this seems to be the location)

In the logs I get the same error.

As per http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/ I then tried to install openssl using rvm like so:

rvm package install openssl

This time, in configure.error.log I get:
[2010-07-07 07:54:28] ./Configure os/compiler darwin-i386-cc -I/Users/craig/.rvm/usr/include -L/Users/craig/.rvm/usr/lib --prefix=/Users/craig/.rvm/usr zlib no-asm no-krb5 shared 
target already defined - os/compiler (offending arg: darwin-i386-cc)

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I know it doesn't help you much, but thanks for the pointer to "rvm package install openssl" -- it fixed the original openssl_missing.o error for me and everything worked fine from there... eventually.

Here's what I ended up doing to get rvm to work on my laptop, minus some silly MacPorts fiddling because I had some old PowerPC binaries installed in /usr/local/lib.

```
rvm package install openssl
rvm package install readline
rvm package install iconv
sudo port install ncurses
sudo port install libyaml
sudo port install zlib
rvm install 1.9.2-head -C "--with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --with-libyaml-dir=/opt/local --with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --with-iconv-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ha! I just tried to install rvm on my work computer and ran into your original problem!

Looks like there was a bug in `~/.rvm/scripts/package`. Try running

```
rvm update --head
```

or

```
rvm get latest
```

to get the latest version from git and try again.

Comment: Haha!  You are correct, sir!  I even tried rvm update, but I didn't include --head.  So glad I randomly came across this via google :-)